# Bias of the MLEs for the two-parameter Weibull distribution

Tags: statistics, estimation

Is it possible to obtain a formula for or an equation on the exact bias of the MLE-vector for the two-parameter Weibull distribution (both parameters unknown). I've read papers offering Monte Carlo studies of how the bias decays as the sample size increases. But is there a way to get some sort of an equation that the bias is to satisfy? Asymptotically as the sample size increases the bias vanishes. But for a finite sample size is the bias even finite?